# Increment and insert in a database SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-insert, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to insert in a database judges in karate competitions, here is my sql string

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO juge @NUM_COMPETITION, @NUM_ENTRAINEUR, (SELECT MAX(NUM_JURY)+1 FROM juge WHERE NUM_COMPETITION = @NUM_COMPETITION);";
```

The problem is that I have multiple competitions, and multiple judges per competition, so I need to find MAX(), increment and insert but I can't manage to do it, could you help me please ?

EDIT : I heard you guys, here is my table [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4XXc.png) and some [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM7iD.png)

Thanks guys !

Comment: where is (values) in your query?

Comment: it should be written like this : string sql = "INSERT INTO juge values(@NUM_COMPETITION, @NUM_ENTRAINEUR, (SELECT MAX(NUM_JURY)+1 FROM juge WHERE NUM_COMPETITION = @NUM_COMPETITION));";

Comment: You should use an auto increment column. It is always a bad idea to try to calculate an id that way.

Comment: @Basta how did you know the table has 3 columns?

Comment: Please add the schema for your tables

Comment: Thanks @Basta for your answer, But it doesn't work, here is the error I got : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'You can't specify target table 'juge' for update in FROM clause'

Answer (score -1):

In the below query replace these fields (#NUM_COMPETITION,#ENTRAINEUR) with the actual column names.

string sql = "INSERT into judge (NUM_JURY,#NUM_COMPETITION,#ENTRAINEUR) values ((SELECT Isnull(MAX(NUM_JURY),0)+1 FROM Judge WHERE NUM_COMPETITION = @NUM_COMPETITION),@NUM_COMPETITION,@NUM_ENTRAINEUR);";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. After i've tweaked it in the right way, the code doesn't work and just tells me syntax error.